# Angular routing in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to read query parameters in my angular controller so I set up the route config
confirmedemailcontroller.js

```
var app = angular.module('confirmedemail', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    // calls
    $routeProvider.when('/confirmedemail/:userid/:token', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/confirmedview.html',
                    controller: 'ConfirmedEmailController'
                });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.controller('ConfirmedEmailController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
    // never calls
    // read params from $routeParams and send them then display the result...
    //...
});
```

ConfirmedEmail.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Confirm Email";
}

    <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
    <div data-ng-app="confirmedemail">
        <p>
            Thank you for confirming your email. Please @Html.ActionLink("Click here to Log in", "Login", "Home", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })
        </p>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

my root is http://localhost:25715/confirmedemail/111/222, 
where *111* is *userId* and *222* is *token* which I want to read out inside controller

But controller never calls. What have I missed?

**Updated**
I have HomeController with working action

```
public ActionResult ConfirmedEmail(string userId = "", string code = "")
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Account confirmed";
    return View();
}
```

and in templates folder there's confirmedview.html

Comment: there isn't really enough code here to reproduce your issue, but the first thing I see is that you have an angular controller with a route provider that would be loading a `confirmedview.html` template, but you show an MVC `ConfirmedEmail.cshtml` file.  does this indicate that you also have a `ConfirmedEmailController` in MVC?

Comment: @Claies yes, I have an appropriate action which works (added some updates)

Comment: I haven't set up an app in quite a while which has two routers interacting like this (I moved to WebAPI and use entirely client side routing now) but I remember something strange about how you had to set up the MVC routes to make this work.   If nobody answers sooner, I'll try to spin up an old site and see if I can't reproduce this issue later in the day.

Comment: I wouldn't set up the angular routes if I had known how to get query parameters another way

Answer (score 0):

In RouteConfig.cs

```
  routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Confirm",
         url: "ConfirmedEmail/{userId}/{code}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ConfirmedEmail", userId = "", code = "" }
     );
```

in confirmedemailcontroller.js

```
var app = angular.module('confirmedemail', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/ConfirmedEmail/:param1/:param2', {
        templateUrl: '/templates/confirmedview.html',
                    controller: 'ConfirmedEmailController'
                });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({ requireBase: false, enabled: true });
});
app.controller('ConfirmedEmailController', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) { ... });
```

And don't forget about case sensivity! If I call it like **mysite.com/confirmedemail/111/222**, it won't work